# A title page set up with correct page count after ToC in crepart

Tags: titles

Please see the writing template I just set up:

```
\documentclass[UTF8,a4paper]{ctexart}
\usepackage[top=.9in, bottom=.8in, left=.8in, right=.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks,bookmarks=true,CJKbookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,unicode=true,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{plain}
\rhead{Some confidential materials}
\lhead{Version 0.1}
\title{The title the title the title}
\author{First Name}
\date{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{第一章}
\subsection{第一节}
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}%unsrt
\bibliography{reference}

\end{document}
```

And the code works good and the result is shown as follows,

[image]

But what I am trying to achieve, are:

1. Add some text blocks shown in the position, (text color is black of course);
2. The page counting starts after ToC.

Because I am writing in Chinese, so the document class `crepart` best fits me. Can anyone give me some instructions and help what kind of package I can use? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to build the `ctexart` class locally, and I had trouble with your chinese characters. However, I feel confident that the following should work:

> 1. Add some text blocks shown in the position, (text color is black of course);

```
\tableofcontents
\vfil%
\hfil TEXT\hfil\makebox[0.5\textwidth]{\hrulefill}\hfil\par
\hfil TEXT\hfil\makebox[0.5\textwidth]{\hrulefill}\hfil
```

> 2. The page counting starts after ToC.

Use `\setcounter{page}{1}` to reset the page counter and
use `\pagenumbering{gobble}` to turn off the page number, and then `\pagenumbering{arabic}` for turning it back on:

Resulting code

```
\documentclass[UTF8,a4paper]{ctexart}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{plain}
\rhead{Some confidential materials}
\lhead{Version 0.1}
\title{The title the title the title}
\author{First Name}
\date{}


\begin{document}
% Turn off pagenumbering
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \vfil%
    \hfil TEXT\hfil\makebox[0.5\textwidth]{\hrulefill}\hfil\par
    \hfil TEXT\hfil\makebox[0.5\textwidth]{\hrulefill}\hfil
\newpage
% Set page number to 1
\setcounter{page}{1}
% Turn on page numbering
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{first}
\subsection{second}
\newpage
\section{third}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}%unsrt
\bibliography{reference}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use differently `\pagestyle` and also issue `\pagenumbering{arabic}` when you want to start the numbering of pages. I also added the recommended `bookmark` package. Note the change to `\headheight`, required by `fancyhdr`.

Since you are using `hyperref`, I added `\pagenumbering{alph}` for the front matter, so to keep `hyperref` happy and not issue duplicate target errors.

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  UTF8,
]{ctexart}

\usepackage[
  top=.9in,
  bottom=.8in,
  left=.8in,
  right=.8in
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[
  colorlinks,
  bookmarks=true,
  CJKbookmarks=true,
  bookmarksnumbered=true,
  unicode=true,
  linkcolor=black,
  anchorcolor=blue,
  citecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\fancypagestyle{first}{%
  \fancyhf{}% clear all fields
  \fancyhead[R]{Some confidential materials}%
  \fancyhead[L]{Version 0.1}%
}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\setlength{\headheight}{13pt} % to keep fancyhdr happy

\title{The title the title the title}
\author{First Name}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{alph} % to keep hyperref happy
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{first}
\clearpage

\pagestyle{empty}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{plain}

\section{北京}
\subsection{北京}
\clearpage

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}%unsrt
\bibliography{reference}

\end{document}
```

**Production notes.** For producing the images I passed `a6paper` to `geometry` just to reduce the image size. I also added `fontset=windows` or I got font errors. Finally, your input produced errors, so I changed it with the Chinese for Beijing.

[image]